# I have multiple products, some with the same OEM code but difference order qty sizes. Need to select certain sizes

Tags: sql

I'm new here and new to SQL. I'm struggling endlessly with a task i've been given and hoping someone can help.

I have a table with lots of products and lots of repetitions of products coming from two tables, but they have different minimum order quantities. I need to select the ones with the best order quantities. here's an example of what I'm looking for.

```
ItemCode    OEMCode         MinOdrQty   VLGX
BLW/B495    FILTER/LF3620   6.00    NULL
DN/P55-2100 FILTER/LF3620   2.00    NULL
FG/LF3620   FILTER/LF3620   0.00    NULL
LBF/LFP2160 FILTER/LF3620   0.00    NULL
```

Okay so the item codes are from different suppliers for the same OEM code. I need to select ONLY ONE row. The row I select must have a sensible MinOrderQty (not negative, not null etc), it must have a VLGX code of NULL, and of the lot I must select the smallest one.

So from the table above, I am looking for the second one. It has a VLGX of null, a valid MinOrderQty, and it is the smaller of the two. Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Which database system are you using? Add a tag with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use WHERE to filter rows. Sort the result in MinOdrQty order, and read the first one (the one with lowest price.)

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE MinOdrQty > 0 AND VLGX IS NULL
ORDER BY MinOdrQty
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

`FETCH FIRST` is ANSI SQL and works with most modern dbms products. `LIMIT` or `TOP` can be needed instead for some products.

**EDIT:** If one row per OEMCode is wanted:

```
with cte as
(
    SELECT * FROM tablename
    WHERE MinOdrQty > 0 AND VLGX IS NULL
)
select * from cte c1
join (select OEMCode, min(MinOdrQty) as MinOdrQty
      from cte
      group by OEMCode) c2
   on c1.OEMCode = c2.OEMCode and c1.MinOdrQty = c2.MinOdrQty
```

**Note:** Will even return 2 rows for an OEMCode in case of a tie!

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis, isn't that what OP wants?  "_I need to select ONLY ONE row."_

Comment: "I need to select the ones with the best order quantities". I guess he needs only one row per OEMCode.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis, hard to tell, since all the rows in the sample data have the same OEMCode...

Comment: Okay this has definitely helped. I think I still have some work to do but it's definitely a step in the right direction. Thanks so much. 

And yes, I would ideally only want one OEMCode row.